# Hibernate entity isn't being persisted but can create table and query

Tags: java, hibernate

my classes seem to be mapped correctly (if I try persist an object it creates the table in the DB (if it's missing)) and I can query succesfully, but I can't get a newly created instance to be persisted to the DB.

I have show SQL queries in console, and it's not generating the insert query, but it's trying to select(max) id afterwards

Could someone please help me figure out why?

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        User myUser = new User();
        myUser.setUserId("Acccc");
        myUser.setPassword("abc");
        session.save(myUser);
```

and class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class User implements Serializable
{
    //Properties
    @Id
    @Column
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String userId;
    @Column
    private String password;

    //Getters
    public int getId() { return id; }
    public String getUserId() { return userId; }
    public String getPassword() { return password; }

    //Setters
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
    public void setUserId(String userId) { this.userId = userId; }
    public void setPassword(String password) { this.password = password; }
}
```

and config:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="nz.co.genesis.healthsafety.stripes.model.User" table="users">
    <id name="id" type="int" column="id" >
    </id>
    <property name="userId" type="java.lang.String" column="userId" not-null="false" length="45" />
    <property name="password" type="java.lang.String" column="password" not-null="false" length="45" />
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And DB:

```
id : PK NN AI
userId varchar45, default NULL
password varchar45, default: null
```

Comment: try changing int to wrapper class Integer

Comment: are you committing the transaction?

Comment: how do I comitt the transaction? I thought .save() did that?

Comment: Maurice Perry, thank you sir! I didn't even have it in a transaction wasn't aware that I needed it it to. Apparently if you have auto-comit mode on Oracle will generate an INSERT but other databases like MySQL won't. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you configuration of the Transaction Hibernate

Comment: Sorry Jelly? Could you please explain? :)

Answer (score 1):

This is my code for test hibernate model

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect");
    props.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
    props.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=databaseName");
    props.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "username");
    props.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "password");

    props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    props.setProperty("hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion", "true");
    props.setProperty("hibernate.connection.release_mode", "auto");
    props.setProperty("hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session", "true");
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.setProperties(props);

    // add dependency table class
    cfg.addClass(ComputerModel.class);
    cfg.addClass(CpuModel.class);       
    cfg.addClass(CdRomModel.class);
    cfg.addClass(BrandModel.class);

    SessionFactory sessions = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session ss = sessions.openSession();
    List<ComputerModel> list = (ss.createQuery("from ComputerModel ")).list();

    System.out.println("Found : " + list.size() + " items.");
    System.out.println("======================================");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        ComputerModel result = (ComputerModel) list.get(i);
        System.out.println("computerSerialNo: " + result.getComputerSerialNo() + 
                           ", " + result.getCpuModel());
    }

    ss.close();
    sessions.close();
}
```